# Hibernate + concurrent inserts (MySQL INSERT IGNORE)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm learning to use Hibernate. I'm wondering how to do concurrent inserts in hibernate properly.

I have an url table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    md5 CHAR(32) UNIQUE, 
    url TEXT
);
```

The table purpose is to maintain a mapping id <-> url.
The md5 field is an md5 sum from url, as in general an url can be longer than 1024 bytes, which is limit for UNIQUE constraint in mysql.

My question is about a query for url -> id function handling concurrency. In JDBC implementation I do these steps:

1. SELECT id WHERE md5=md5(url);
2. if exists, return id, else:
3. INSERT IGNORE INTO urls (md5,url) VALUES (MD5(url), url);
4. retry step 1.

It works nice even when requested url is inserted between steps 2 and 3. How do I do this with Hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

You can play around with the annotation [@SQLInsert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-customsql). It allows you to specify which SQL statement to use during inserts. The problem is: Hibernate does a lot more than just inserting/updating/selecting data from the database. That said, I'm quite sure that just by using @SQLInsert may work at first, but I'm not sure how Hibernate will behave when you hit the scenario you described (a concurrent insert between steps 2 and 3), specially because it doesn't performs the step 4. Instead, it calls JDBC's "getGeneratedKeys" to retrieve which ID was generated (which, I suspect, would be null if the insert was ignored).

In short: the only solution that I see is using @SQLInsert, but you will want to play with that and make sure Hibernate behaves correctly when a concurrent insert happens.